# $\mathbb{R}^n$ has no order compatible with addition

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

My lecture notes on real analysis mention that we cannot order the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a way that respects vector addition:

> $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the structure of a vector space:
>
> - Componentwise addition defines the additive Abelian group ($\mathbb{R}^n$; +), whose neutral element (0,...,0)^T we also denote by 0.
> - Multiplication with a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is also defined componentwise, $\lambda x := (\lambda x_1,...,\lambda x_n)^T$.
>   For us a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is also a vector, and vice versa. For $n \geq 2$ there exists no ordering on $\mathbb{R}^n$ compatible with addition.

Naturally this is a proof by contradiction, but I just don't know where to start.

I have proven this for the complex field before, but I doubt that the same proof will work as it uses the fact that $i^2=-1$, which we don't have here. In addition, we don't even have multiplication of elements but only scalar multiplication.

Can anybody please point into the right direction?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we make $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ an ordered field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217096/can-we-make-mathbbr2-an-ordered-field)

Comment: @Kaira - This question doesn't make reference to any possible multiplication.

Comment: What is your definition of "respects vector addition"?  For the most obvious way of defining it, this is not true.

Comment: @EricWofsey That might be tricky to clarify, if this is just a throw-away remark in the lecture notes. I think it's reasonable to assume that it is the obvious way of defining it.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have edited the question to reflect that we are talking about $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space, so the addition and scalar multiplication are the "usual" ones.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy I think Eric is asking about how the order is supposed to "respect" this addition. I would take it to mean $v \le w \implies v + u \le w + u$ for all $u, v, w$. Perhaps even $\alpha v \ge 0$ whenever $\alpha \ge 0$ and $v \ge 0$? Do the lecture notes offer any clarification on this point?

Comment: But what do you mean by "respects"?  You also talk about "having scalar multiplication", but you have only mentioned respecting addition, not scalar multiplication, so it would seem you don't "have" scalar multiplication in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, I think this is what the author meant, but since it is only mentioned as an aside there is no additional information except that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot think of any reasonable interpretation of the statement which would make this true.  For instance, consider the following ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$: we say $(a,b)\leq (c,d)$ iff either $a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b\leq d$.  This is a total order, and it satisfies any reasonable compatibility with the vector space structure you could ask for.  In particular, if $x\leq y$ then $x+z\leq y+z$ for any $z$ and $cx\leq cy$ for any scalar $c\geq 0$.

(This is known as the "lexicographic order".  Intuitively, you can think of it as identifying $(a,b)$ with "$a+b\epsilon$" where $\epsilon$ is some infinitely small positive quantity.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the lexicographic order, right? I also played around with this and basically came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy I suspect you're not going to get an answer better than this, so you should mark it as accepted. Feel free to wait if you disagree, but Eric's interpretation is, IMHO, the only reasonable interpretation. I suspect that whomever wrote the notes was thinking of the problem that Kaira pointed to in the above comments.